# Possible to acquire a Dutch passport with dutch grandparents?

Tags: passports, netherlands, dual-nationality, dutch-citizens

I would like to travel to Europe (and maybe live/study) and having a Dutch passport would be extremely useful.

**My situation:** My grandparents were Dutch and migrated to New Zealand many years ago. My father was born here in New Zealand before they got residency (I think). My grandparents are now deceased.

Is it possible for either me and/or my father to get a Dutch passport?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  This question is more appropriate for our sister site: expatriates.SE.

Comment: I understand that [Dutch nationality law restricts dual citizenship to only certain cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_nationality_law#Dual_citizenship), and it doesn't sound like your case would qualify. However, being a New Zealand citizen does get you certain advantages for European visits, see [Visa policy of the Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area) and search for "New Zealand" on that page for some details.

Comment: What extreme usefulness do you expect from a Dutch citizenship when travelling in Europe? Unless you are planning to move permanently, you won't have any obvious issues using your existing nationality.

Comment: @Karlson I originally agreed, but technically he's looking for one to travel with - he has no (visible) intention of moving to the Netherlands.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Sorry, yes I would like to have the option to live and more importantly study in the Netherlands in the future if possible.

Comment: @Karlson Ok, thanks. Should I then delete the question?

Comment: @MarkMayo how should I take: *and maybe live/study*?

Comment: @Karlson Marks comment was posted before I updated the question with live/study. :)

Comment: @Karlson well *now* it is...

Comment: This website lists the rules for who can apply for Dutch citizenship or have it and can apply for proof, based on parents and grand parents nationalty: https://www.government.nl/topics/dutch-nationality/contents/becoming-a-dutch-national

Comment: @GregHewgill if a person has Dutch nationality and another nationality, both through the circumstances of birth, Dutch law permits dual nationality.  That would be the case here, if indeed the OP qualifies.

Answer (score 4):

There is a page specifically dealing with your situation though from the [Dutch Embassy in the UK](http://unitedkingdom.nlembassy.org/passports-visas--consular/dutch-nationality):

> **Dutch nationality**
>
> A Dutch passport or identity card can only be issued to a Dutch national. You can find more information on the ways in which a person can acquire Dutch nationality under current Dutch nationality law on the Dutch government's website.
>
> Nationality issues can be quite complex, especially those where one of the (great)grandparents was the Dutch national. The Embassy is not in a position to undertake nationality investigations as these can be very time-consuming. You may wish to contact a solicitor in the Netherlands who specializes in nationality law to obtain his/her opinion on your nationality status.
>
> If you have all the necessary documents to show that you acquired Dutch nationality through your Dutch (grand)father or Dutch mother, then please read the information on this website with respect to a first time passport application.
>
> If you are not a Dutch national yet but think that you are eligible to apply for Dutch nationality and you are living in the UK, then please read the information on the page 'Applying for Dutch nationality' before contacting the embassy.

You can look at the [Dutch Government site for more information](https://www.government.nl/topics/dutch-nationality/contents/dutch-nationality-by-birth-or-family-ties) but as the embassy site suggests you should find a solicitor specializing in the citizenship cases and contact them for more help.

Comment: @Willeke Problem is that the OP only has a confirmed knowledge of grandparents.

Comment: @Willeke I agree that's why the page from embassy is actually more helpful then the last link. :)